# clang-format 14: Unexpected empty line after `requires` declarations

Tags: c++, clang-format

I use `clang-format` to format my code. I would like to have a class declaration like this:

```cpp
template <class C>
requires Foo<C>
class Baz {
  // ...
};
```

But when I hit format, clang-format has to format my file with an "extra" empty line after the `requires` declaration and before `class`:

```cpp
template <class C>
requires Foo<C>
                          // <- what is this??
class Baz {
  // ...
};
```

I have not found anything that mentions "empty line before `requires` declarations" in the clang-format docs.
I have tried to use `MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 0` in my `.clang-format` but actually, it's a very bad option for me. How can I fix it?